# How create a new method in my controller in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I want to generate a method in my controller "Applications" in Ruby on Rails, bur i used scaffold and now I dont know if have to create a new view too.

```
  def list
    @applications = Application.all

  end
```

I only want that my controller give me all the applications objects, but I dont know if I have to create a new View.

Comment: whats wrong with using the existing `index` action for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a view if you are going to display the `@applications`.  Create a new file `app/views/applications/list.html.erb` if you are using `erb` of course.

You also need to add a route to this `list` action if you haven't done that already.  I'm assuming a get request as your code only shows retrieval of `Application`.  In your `config/routes.rb` add the following lines:

```
resources :applications do 
  collection do 
    get :list
  end
end
```

Once these are done you'll have `/applications/list` path which will execute the `list` action of your `ApplicationsController` and the view `list.html.erb`.

Comment: Great answer. Very helpful =) But now, I want to know if i did the scaffolding, I have this in my routes "resources :applications", and when i use that code you told me I got that error: "undefined method `collections'". Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @CrisTowi, sorry that was a typo.  It should have been `collection`, not `collections`.  Corrected my answer as well.

Comment: @CrisTowi, Great.  Glad to be of help.